# How to write schema in mongoose for storing object of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store an Object which contains collection of object like below example,

```
{
    basic1: { ischecked: false, ans: "" },
    basic2: { ischecked: false, ans: "" },
    basic3: { ischecked: false, ans: "" },
    basic4: { ischecked: false, ans: "" },
    basic5: { ischecked: false, ans: "" },
}
```

Can someone tell me how can i write a schema for the same to store in answers field in the below code,

```
 const BasicQ = mongoose.model("basicq", {
  userid: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Users",
  },
  answers: ???,
});
```

The the data should store in mongodb something like this,

```
{
  _id: dad3434v,
  userid: dasdadad232,
  answers: {
    basic1: { },
    basic2: { },
    basic3: { },
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an empty object, u can store these all object

```
const BasicQ = mongoose.model("basicq", {
  userid: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Users",
  },
  answers: {},
});
```

Comment: But it would store it as a string rather than object